# Is the following an example of a non-measurable event?

Tags: measure-theory

Goodmorning everyone.

I started reading DeGroot and Schervish's 'Probability and Statistics' (4th editon) and wondered,  is there an uncountable union of events, that is not an event?

This question has been answered on this site.
The topic of question is "What is an uncountable union of events?" (sorry ba I can't report the code or the link of the question that has already been answered).

The responses were very illuminating,
however, re-reading the example of an uncountable union of events that is not an event, I'm referring to Arthur's answer, I wonder if the example is adequate. This confuses me.

I report the example referred to in the aforementioned answer and then I ask my question.

*Example:*
Assuming the Axiom of Choice (which is a very reasonable and common thing to do, but not universal), you can construct unions of events which, if allowed to be events themselves, will have a problematic probability of ocurring. Basically, it can't be 0 and it can't be positive.

To see it in action, let's say your experiment is to pick a point uniformly at random on a circle. Then any point is an event. Using the AoC, we can construct (or more correctly, we can prove the existence of) a set of points A0 on the circle with a special property: Rotating the set along the circle by any rational angle α∈(0∘,360∘) results in a new set of points Aα. None of these Aα have any points in common with any of the others, but together they cover the entire circle.

So, if we were to assign some probability p to picking a point in A0, then by rotational symmetry the same probability should apply to any of the Aα. And since they are all pairwise disjoint, and they together cover the circle, the sum of all those p's should be 1. Thus we have
∑α∈[0,360)∩Qp=1

But if p is 0, the sum is 0, and if p is positive, then the sum is infinite. So it is impossible to assign a probability to this union A0, and therefore we are better off not calling it an event.

*Question*
Why can't I consider the set of rational points to have zero measure? If I imagine the circle composed of rational and irrational points, why not assign a measure of nothing on the first (rational) and measure equal to 1 on the second (irrational)? so, having admitted the above, am I wrong if I consider the circle as a union of rational and irrational points?

Thanks for any answer or clarification.

Francesco.

Comment: This question would be improved if you could provide a link to the other question.

Comment: I try to link the link of the post to which I refer. qui https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3162961/871304

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Thanks Ramiro. Yes, the answer was helpful. I voted. I hope I have done everything correctly.

Comment: Now I look at the set of Vitali. I think I have perceived the meaning, even if I still cannot frame it and make it mine. What deceived me was the erroneous view that caught a point and "rotated" a razoinal number, I lost the irrational numbers.
It seems to me that with the set of Vitali, I draw a number, "rotate" it by a rational number and cover the whole circle (rational and otherwise). From here it is easy to demonstrate that I cannot assign a measure. In any case I will deepen as soon as I have time (I do it as a "hobby"). Thanks again.

Comment: @Francesco , I have added a second **Remark** to my answer, explaining the "Vitali set" in the circle. Please, take a look.

Comment: Please,  if my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, would you mind **upvoting** my answer?  To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question.

Comment: @Ramiro, I should have voted. If you don't find it, let me know, I'll try again. Thanks again. Sorry, I just registered and have not yet learned all the mechanisms of the site.

Comment: It worked. You upvoted. Thanks. I understand that for new users the mechanisms of the site are not self-evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us divide the answer in two parts:

1. Consider the space $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue measure.
   We know that there are subsets of $[0,1]$ that are not Lebesgue. One of such subsets is the Vitali set. Let $V$ be the Vitali set. Then $V$ is uncountable and it is not an event. On the other hand, every single point in $V$ is an event (is measurable). So $V$ is an example of an uncountable union of events that is not an event.

(For more details on Vitali set, see, for instance : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set)

2. Arthur answer's in [What is an uncountable union of events?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162954/what-is-an-uncountable-union-of-events/3162961#3162961) includes the "construction" of a non-measurable subset in the circle, very similar to the Vitali subset of $[0,1]$ .

If you want to go deeper and understand the proof of the existence of Vitali set, I suggest you do it, with the usual Vitali set (subset of $[0,1]$). After that, you can read Arthur's answer and see how the same argument is adapetd to the circle.

**Remark 1**: Regarding your questions at the end.

"Why can't I consider the set of rational points to have zero measure?"

Answer: the set rational points has zero measure

"If I imagine the circle composed of rational and irrational points, why not assign a measure of nothing on the first (rational) and measure equal to 1 on the second (irrational)?"

Answer: Assuming the circle has measure 1, the set of irrational points has measure 1.

"Am I wrong if I consider the circle as a union of rational and irrational points?"

Answer: No, you are not wrong. But Arthur's answer is not about this.

**Remark 2**: Explaining the "Vitali set" in the circle.

You don't get just one point to perform rational rotations.

Given any angle $\theta \in [0^\circ, 360^\circ)$, let us write $R_\theta$ to indicate the rotation by $\theta$.

You first consider the equivalence relation between points in the circle:
$x \sim y$ iff there a rational angle $\alpha$ such that the $R_\alpha(x)=y$. It is easy to see that such relation is actually an equivalence relation.

Then (using the Axiom of Choice) we choose one and just one element (one point) **from each** equivalence class and with them we have a set $A$. Note that $A$ has two interesting properties:

1. For any two rational angles $\alpha, \beta$, if $\alpha \neq \beta$, then $R_\alpha(A) \cap R_\beta(A) =\emptyset$.
2. If $C$ is the whole circle,
   $$C = \bigcup_{\alpha \textrm{ rational angle in } [0^\circ, 360^\circ)} R_\alpha(A)$$

In fact, for 1: Let $\beta'$ be the (rational) angle in $[0^\circ, 360^\circ)$ congruent to $-\beta$ and let $\gamma$ be the (rational) angle in $[0^\circ, 360^\circ)$ congruent to $\alpha-\beta$.
If there is $p\in R_\alpha(A) \cap R_\beta(A)$, then
there is $q=R_{\beta'}(p)$ and  $q \in R_\gamma(A) \cap A$. But it means that $q \in A$ and there is $q_1 \in A$ such that $q=R_\gamma(q_1)$. Since $\alpha \neq\beta$, we have $\gamma \neq 0$ and $q \neq q_1$. But $q \sim q_1$. However, it is not possible, because in $A$ there is only one representative of each equivalence class.

For 2: Just note that every point of the circle is in one equivalence class. It means that, for every $p$ in the circle, there is $q\in A$ and a rational angle $\alpha \in [0^\circ, 360^\circ)$, such that $p=R_\alpha(q)$.

Since the set of rational angle is countable, the measure of the whole circle is finite, and for any rational angle $\alpha \in  [0^\circ, 360^\circ)$, $R_\alpha(A)$ would have the same measure of $A$, we conclude that $A$ is not measurable (it is not an event).

**Remark 3**: @Francesco, to answer your questions in the comments,
let me give more details regarding the "Vitali set" in the circle.

Let us pick just one point $p$ in the circle. By applying rotations by a rational angle, we produce a countable set of points (why countable? because there are only a countable "quantity" of rational angles). This countable set of points is the equivalence class of $p$.  In this equivalence class you must pick exactly one point to represent the equivalence class.

Is it possible that this equivalence class includes all points in the circle?  The answer is NO, because the circle is an uncountable set of points. So, there are others equivalence classes, all of them countable sets.  In fact, it is known that taking the union of any countable family of countable sets produces a countable set as result. Since the circle is uncountable, we can conclude that there is an uncountable "quantity" of such equivalence classes.

A simple example that one such equivalence does not include the whole circle is:  let us start with the point at $0^\circ$. Any rotation by a rational angle wil produce a point located at a rational angle. So, for instance, the point located at angle ${\sqrt{2}\,}^\circ$ can not be produced from our initial point by a rotation by a rational angle.

Another point that you need to keep in mind is that for any set $S$ and any equivalence relation on $S$, the equivalence classes are disjoint  and the union of all equivalence classes is the $S$ (that is, every point of $S$ is one equivalence class).

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation.
You have been helpful and patient. Unfortunately, due to my limitations, I still cannot grasp the correct interpretation. A little for macate knowledge (I'm afraid), and a little for unresolved issues that undermine my mind
In particular, I admit that I cannot imagine A, or rather, that I am not sure I can imagine it correctly. I consider a point of the circle, p1. If it is in "alpha" relation with another point, which I identify with R (p1), I choose one of the two: let's say p1.

Comment: Then I go on to consider another point, p2 which is in "alpha" relation with its equivalent R (p2). I choose, p2 ... and so on. If so, the choice is between two elements (and here I begin to fear that something escapes me, because the process of choice apparently too simple according to my vision). In any case, by doing so, the set A consists of (p1, p2, ... etc.). If my reasoning, up to here, is correct, I will continue to study your explanation.
The question that undermines my mind is instead the following:

Comment: if I have not misunderstood, x is related to y if there is a rotation of a rational angle that from x makes me obtain y. But is it possible that y is not obtainable by applying a rotation of a rational angle? in other words, could Y be obtained, just by turning an irrational angle? maybe it is stupid, what I ask, but the question is an obstacle to understanding the next passage which states that the countable union on rational angles of the equivalence relations make me obtain the whole circle (because if I miss that particular y the circle is not whole).

Comment: @Francesco Since the answer was little long, I have added it to the answer as **Remark 3**. Please, take a look and let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Ok, very useful. I try to take stock of the situation.
Taking up your clarification number 3, in particular the last sentence, let S be the circle. Each point of S is an equivalence class. The uncountable union of these equivalence classes is S itself (i.e. the whole circle). Furthermore: suppose that every point of S is an event. The uncountable union of these events is something we decide to call non-event.We call it non-event because we can't assign a "coherent" measure (pass me the imprecise term) to this non-event.

Comment: However, something still escapes me.
If I assign zero measure to every single event (I mean a generic measure, not necessarily Lebesque) to the non-event I should assign zero measure: possible but not logical. a circle with zero measurement? no. So let's suppose that every single event has assigned a measure (always generic). Then the non-event would have infinite measure. This too is not very logical. And now comes the doubt ...

Comment: If I assign measure (or in this case probability) zero to all points except one, on which I assign measure 1, then the measure of the circle will be 1. This appears consistent with expectations. So, I ask myself: is the problem of a non-nuberable union of events, which should be considered a non-event, strictly related to the Lebesque measure?

Comment: @Francesco Each point is IN an equivalence class. It is not by itself an equivalence class. The circle is uncountable union of sets with just one point but the circle is measurable. It is an event. The vitali set $A$ (which is also uncountable) is not an event.

Comment: Thanks again for the infinite patience. This constant exchange of explanations I imagine it is exhausting for you. I don't bother you anymore (at least on this issue). If it can console you, know that it has been very useful for me, and I will always be grateful to you. Thanks to your answers, in addition to having learned many new things, I now believe I have solved my question: I mistakenly believed that every uncountable union creates problems when I go to assign a measure and that therefore - to define probability - it is not required that this uncountable union be an event.

Comment: In fact, if I understand correctly, the problem of the impossibility of assigning a measure does not arise on every set that is uncountable union (for example the circle is measurable) but "only" on some (for example the set of Vitali). Ok, if I understand correctly now I will try because this "problem" does not exist if I consider "only" the countable unions. Thanks again @ Ramiro. An uncountable infinity of thanks for the time you have dedicated to me.

Comment: @Francesco, You are very welcome. Yes you understood correctly. There many uncountable set that are measurable (the circle, $[0,1]$, the real line $\Bbb R$, etc...). On the other hand, given that  the sets having just a single point are are measurable, the any countable set is measurable. If fact any countanble union of measurable sets is measurable.